# Ubuntu 18.04 slow unlock/boot (black screen for couple of seconds)

Tags: boot, 18.04

After executing the command 
**dmesg**
I got these errors.

```
         0.052980] ACPI Error: No handler for Region [RAM_] (0000000026f4e6f0)
     [EmbeddedControl] (20170831/evregion-166)
        [    0.052987] ACPI Error: Region EmbeddedControl (ID=3) has no handler (20170831/exfldio-299)
         0.053006] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed \_SB.PCI0.LPCB.EC0._REG, AE_NOT_EXIST (20170831/psparse-550)
        [    0.053191] ACPI Error: No handler for Region [RAM_] (0000000026f4e6f0) [EmbeddedControl] (20170831/evregion-166)
        [    0.053196] ACPI Error: Region EmbeddedControl (ID=3) has no handler (20170831/exfldio-299)

         0.053211] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed \_SB.PCI0.LPCB.EC0._REG, AE_NOT_EXIST (20170831/psparse-550)

         0.167726] platform MSFT0101:00: failed to claim resource 1: [mem 0xfed40000-0xfed40fff]
        [    0.167731] acpi MSFT0101:00: platform device creation failed: -16
        [    1.453288] Couldn't get size: 0x800000000000000e
        [    1.453291] MODSIGN: Couldn't get UEFI db list
        [    3.333114] acer_wmi: Unsupported machine has AMW0_GUID1, unable to load
        [    8.618998] aufs aufs_fill_super:912:mount[1442]: no arg
        [    8.630848] overlayfs: missing 'lowerdir'


 gnome-session-binary[1086]: CRITICAL: Unable to create a DBus proxy for GnomeScreensaver: Error calling StartServiceByName for org.gnome.ScreenSaver: GDBus.Error:org.freedeskt


 wpa_supplicant[907]: dbus: fill_dict_with_properties dbus_interface=fi.w1.wpa_supplicant1.Interface dbus_property=Stations getter failed
 wpa_supplicant[907]: dbus: wpa_dbus_get_object_properties: failed to get object properties: (none) none
 wpa_supplicant[907]: dbus: Failed to construct signal

gnome-session-binary[1086]: Unrecoverable failure in required component org.gnome.Shell.desktop

spice-vdagent[1573]: Cannot access vdagent virtio channel /dev/virtio-ports/com.redhat.spice.0

pulseaudio[2141]: [pulseaudio] bluez5-util.c: GetManagedObjects() failed: org.freedesktop.systemd1.NoSuchUnit: Unit dbus-org.bluez.service not found.
```

**systemd-analyze blame**

```
         22.796s fstrim.service
         14.078s apt-daily.service
          5.078s bolt.service
          3.911s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
          3.599s apt-daily-upgrade.service
          1.128s plymouth-start.service
```

Comment: I installed the microcode, it doesn't fix the unlock/boot slowness.

Comment: Also, some jobs that are taking too long.
By running  systemd-analyze blame

22.796s fstrim.service
         14.078s apt-daily.service
          5.078s bolt.service
          3.911s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
          3.599s apt-daily-upgrade.service
          1.128s plymouth-start.service

Comment: The slow boot is caused by `fstrim` which normally should only be run once a week. If memory serves me correctly, others have reported a similar problem.

Comment: How can i fix this?

Comment: Is fstrim being run every boot or just once a week?

Comment: runs at every boot. I went back to 17.10 and everything works fine. I will wait couple of months until 18.04 runs smoother.